# rxjs return value from second request

Tags: ajax, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem with return Observable from second request.
Something like this:

```
commandRequest(action:string, commandData:any):Observable<CashDesckResponse>
{
    let command:CashDeskRequest;
    //ask my backend for command
    this.requestCommandString(action, commandData, "POST")
        //this is my response from backend
        .map(r=>r.response).subscribe(my_1_response=>{
        //then i need to send this response data to other server/action 
        //to execute it and return this second response as the result of
        //this method.
        command = new CashDesckRequest(my_1_response);
        return this.server.executeCommand(command).map(return_this=>return_this);
    }); 
};

private requestCommandString(action:string, requestData:any,
                             type:string):Observable<AjaxResponse>{
    return Observable.ajax({
        body:JSON.stringify(requestData),
        method:type,
        url:this._apiServerUrl+action
    }).map(r=>r);
};
```

My problem that the commandRequest return value from first .map(). And if i`ll try to return value from inner subscribe compiller throw error:
[ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
https://habrastorage.org/web/93b/e6b/17b/93be6b17bf5b46b5847e67deefd6eea1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map from one stream to another you can use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) or [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

```
commandRequest(action:string, commandData:any):Observable<CashDesckResponse>
{
    return this.requestCommandString(action, commandData, "POST")
        .map(r1 => new CashDesckRequest(r1.response)
        // map first response to command instance
        .mergeMap(command =>this.server.executeCommand(command));
        // map the command observable to a new observable
}
```